# detect widget rotation

Tags: android, widget, rotation

i have developed and android widget but i need to detect rotaion. i have googeled but not found a solution. when i rotate the simulator it uses the suitable layout (under the layout-land) but does not load the data. when i click any button on the widget it loads the data.

thanks.

this code is not allowed.

```
    @Override 
public void onEnabled(Context context) { 
    super.onEnabled(context); 
    this.registerReceiver(this, new
```

IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED)); 
    }